# Error:Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [org.apache.logging.log4j.core]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, log4j2

I am using Android Studio 3.0.8, gradle - 4.1.

I've added in my module build.gradle log4j2 dependency and necessary for it annotation processor:

```
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8"
annotationProcessor 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8'
```

But I've got the error:

> Error:Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments 
>   [org.apache.logging.log4j.core] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Annotation process is enabled in default settings: https://yadi.sk/i/MinCMsK33LZkjM

I am using libgdx. Build.gradle (module - core):

```
apply plugin: "java"

targetCompatibility = 1.8
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}

dependencies {
    compile  "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8"
    annotationProcessor 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8'
}
```

I was trying to add it to project build.gradle, invalidate cash. But error remains the same. Gradle can not apply annotationProcessor to log4j2.

Comment: Why you try to use `log4j-core` as annotationProcessor?

Comment: Because gradle demands either enable annotationProcessor for org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8 or switch includeCompileClasspath to true. It recomends enable abnnotationProcessor.

Comment: DeKaNszn, because gradle demands it:Error:Execution failed for task ':android:java-precompile debug'.
> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
    - log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Comment: Could you post your full `build.gradle` files?

Comment: lu.koerfer, please check question, I've added build.gradle.